# How to import code from Workspace to a method from inside Workspace

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I want to send code from my workspace to a method. This means create the class and then the method without ever leaving the workspace or using the Browser. Is this possible and if yes how ?

Can I do the same for creating tests ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in a workspace:

```
|myClass myTest|

myClass := Object subclass: #MyClass
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'GeneratedInAWorkspace'.

myClass compile: 'foo ^ 10'.

myTest := TestCase subclass: #MyClassTest
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'GeneratedInAWorkspace'.

myTest compile: 'testFoo self assert: (Smalltalk at: #MyClass) new foo = 10'.
myTest run: #testFoo "prints: 1 run, 1 passes, 0 skipped, 0 expected failures, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 unexpected passes"
```

Comment: works exactly as I wanted. I knew about the message to create the class because I have seen it used by the browser but I had no clue how to create the method and it was that simple. Brilliant, thank you very much :)